# $(∀x < y)(x ∈ β) ⇒ y ∈ β$, Prove$\beta=\alpha$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, ordinals

Here $α$ is an ordinal number and $β ⊆ α$ has the property
$(∀x < y)(x ∈ β) ⇒ y ∈ β$
for every $y ∈ α$. Prove that $β = α$.

Any help will be appreciate. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Suppose it's not the case. What can we do with $\operatorname{min}\alpha\setminus\beta$?

Comment: @Fallen apart Yes,x is in$\alpha$ because x is in $\beta$ which is a subset of $\alpha$. And $y$ is already told to be in it.

Comment: @Renan Maneli Mezabarba Do you mean trying to get a contradiction. Seems possible because if we take the difference then it is a subset of an ordinal and hence has we can get a contradiction which is related to the minimal element. Maybe for the minimal element of the difference set we can find some y >x and y is not in $\alpha$. May I please ask for a solution?

Comment: May I ask why someone downvotes this question?

Comment: @RenanManeliMezabarba: I've tried, but where to find an element in $\alpha$ such that $x<y$ and $y\notin \beta$? Or is not the right track?

Comment: @RenanManeliMezabarba：Is that for all $y\in \alpha-\beta, x\le y$ but $y\notin \beta$?

Comment: I didn't downvote but maybe it's because you didn't include anything about what you tried in your question. You don't seem to be new here, but even then you still can take the Tour (http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) and read through the Help Center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\lambda$ be the least element in $\alpha$ such that $\lambda\not\in\beta$. Then $\forall \delta <\lambda,\delta\in\beta$ and so by the property, $\lambda\in\beta\bot$